# How to not repeat myself in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found myself writing similar code a few times and im not sure of the best way to do it.

i have a few divs:

```
    <div id="gallery1">
    some content
</div>

<div id="gallery2">
    some content
</div>

<div id="gallery3">
    some content
</div>

<div id="gallery4">
    some content
</div>

<div id="gallery5">
    some content
</div>

<div id="gallery6">
    some content
</div>
```

i will hide gallery 2 - 6 in css and then show them using jquery with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    // shows gallery 1

    $('.gallery1show').click(function(){

        // prevents link from going anywhere

        event.preventDefault();

        // shows gallery 1

        $('#gallery1').show();

        // hides other galleries

        $('#gallery2').hide();
        $('#gallery3').hide();
        $('#gallery4').hide();
        $('#gallery5').hide();
        $('#gallery6').hide();

    });


    // shows gallery 2

    $('.gallery2show').click(function(){

        // prevents link from going anywhere

        event.preventDefault();

        // shows gallery 2

        $('#gallery2').show();

        // hides other galleries

        $('#gallery1').hide();
        $('#gallery3').hide();
        $('#gallery4').hide();
        $('#gallery5').hide();
        $('#gallery6').hide();

    });


    // shows gallery 3

    $('.gallery3show').click(function(){

        // prevents link from going anywhere

        event.preventDefault();

        // shows gallery 3

        $('#gallery3').show();

        // hides other galleries

        $('#gallery1').hide();
        $('#gallery2').hide();
        $('#gallery4').hide();
        $('#gallery5').hide();
        $('#gallery6').hide();

    });


    ... etc


});
```

i got a feeling that rather than using gallery1, gallery2 etc i should just give each div a class of gallery and then use this and not this in jquery. but im not sure where to start.

any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```js
var galleries = $('.gallery');
$('.show-gallery').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var gallery = $($(this).attr('href'));
  galleries.not(gallery).hide();
  gallery.show();
});
```

```css
.gallery + .gallery {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery1" class="gallery">gallery 1</div>
<div id="gallery2" class="gallery">gallery 2</div>
<div id="gallery3" class="gallery">gallery 3</div>
<div id="gallery4" class="gallery">gallery 4</div>
<div id="gallery5" class="gallery">gallery 5</div>

<a href="#gallery1" class="show-gallery">Gallery 1</a>
<a href="#gallery2" class="show-gallery">Gallery 2</a>
<a href="#gallery3" class="show-gallery">Gallery 3</a>
<a href="#gallery4" class="show-gallery">Gallery 4</a>
<a href="#gallery5" class="show-gallery">Gallery 5</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make all div a common class "gallery" and hide it

```
$(".gallery").hide();
```

and show only that gallery which is require

```
$("#gallery1").show();
```

or write code is such a way that jQuery identify div dynamically to show it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.show').on('click',function() {
    $('.gallery').hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
});
```

```css
.gallery {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#gallery1" class="show">Show gallery 1</a>
<a href="#gallery2" class="show">Show gallery 2</a>
<a href="#gallery3" class="show">Show gallery 3</a>
<a href="#gallery4" class="show">Show gallery 4</a>
<a href="#gallery5" class="show">Show gallery 5</a>
<a href="#gallery6" class="show">Show gallery 6</a>

<div id="gallery1" class="gallery"> 
    some content 1
</div>

<div id="gallery2" class="gallery">
    some content 2
</div>

<div id="gallery3" class="gallery">
    some content 3
</div>

<div id="gallery4" class="gallery">
    some content 4
</div>

<div id="gallery5" class="gallery">
    some content 5
</div>

<div id="gallery6" class="gallery">
    some content 6
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but here's a working example : https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Guess you have given partial of your html code there, hence I assume it has some buttons to trigger the show action of gallery. Below is on that assumption how your HTML has to be

```
<div class="galleries">
  <div id="gallery1" class="gallery active">
    gallery 1    
  </div>
  <div id="gallery2" class="gallery">
    gallery 2   
  </div>
  <div id="gallery3" class="gallery">
    gallery 3   
  </div>
  <div id="gallery4" class="gallery">
    gallery 4   
  </div>
  <div id="gallery5" class="gallery">
    gallery 5    
  </div>
  <div id="gallery6" class="gallery">
    gallery 6  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-buttons">
  <button data-id="1">Gallery 1</button>  <button data-id="2">Gallery 2</button>
  <button data-id="3">Gallery 3</button>
  <button data-id="4">Gallery 4</button>
  <button data-id="5">Gallery 5</button>
  <button data-id="6">Gallery 6</button>
</div>
```

and css

```
.gallery{
  display:none;
}

.gallery.active{
  display:block;
}
```

and the js

```
$('.gallery-buttons button').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $('.gallery.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.gallery[id="gallery'+id+'"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Here is a demo pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGJaNM